# InfluxDB how to get the last recorded values

Tags: java, database, influxdb

There is an Inflix DB database in which values are written. How do I get the last recorded data (for example, protocol number and time in long) for a device named "test"?  I tried to get it through `query`, but it returns only one point, although there are about 40 of them in the database.

Below is a sample code.

```
public static long getTime( String devName ) {

        InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://10.10.1.72:8086");
        String sql = "select time, protocol from device";
        Query query = new Query( sql, dbName );
        QueryResult result = influxDB.query(query);

        Series series = result.getResults().get(0).getSeries().get(0);

        //long time = (long)(double)series.getValues().get(0).get(0);
        System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(0) + "=" + series.getValues().get(0).get(0) + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(0).getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(series.getColumns().get(1) + "=" + series.getValues().get(0).get(1) + " " + series.getValues().get(0).get(1).getClass().getName());
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the last item using `last` function:

```
SELECT last(protocol) FROM device [optional: WHERE <your condition>]
```

or you can use `LIMIT` keyword (note that, we should use descending order):

```
SELECT * FROM device ORDER BY desc LIMIT 1
```